# Does Ahsoka know when Obi-Wan and Anakin die?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, anakin-skywalker, ahsoka-tano

Not sure if this has ever been revealed or discussed, but I always wondered whether she knew when exactly these two died as she would have only been in her 30's when they passed. Also does anyone know whether she ever sees Obi-Wan again?

Comment: Unknown at this time. The last canon appearances of Ahsoka occurs prior to ANH and after RoTJ and it's certain she knows they are dead by that point (post RoTJ), but as to a scene in book or TV where she feels it at the moment - no (not yet anyway)

Comment: It is known that Ahsoka survives the Battle of Endor. As she is Force-sensitibve, it is quite possible that she could have felt their death through the Force.

Answer (score 2):

**It is unclear in what timeline Ahsoka exists**

As we all know, time travel was introduced in *Rebels* episode [A World Between Worlds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_World_Between_Worlds). In that episode Ezra saves Ahsoka from Vader by pulling her from Sith Temple on Malachor, thus alternating original timeline. Later, while fleeing from Palpatine, Ahsoka returns to the Temple, but again it is not clear what timeline is this. Finally in final episode :) of the *Rebels*, we see her meeting Sabine Wren after Empire collapsed.

Of course, in original trilogy Ahsoka does not exist, and neither Obi-Wan or Vader meet her or mention her. Unless Disney retcons something, she has no influence on Rebellion and Galactic Civil War since her disappearance on Malachor. This leads us to conclusion, no matter how confusing this is, that original trilogy plays out in a timeline without Ahsoka, and that she exists in her own timeline, possibly somehow traveling back to meet Sabine.

Out of universe, because of Disney's inept storytelling, many fans simply choose to ignore *Rebels* final episodes, and consider Ahsoka to be dead in main timeline displayed in original trilogy.

Comment: This answer is flawed because Star Wars is not a "multiple timeline" universe. This is shown in Rebels when she convinces Ezra to not to save his mentor by pulling him into the pocket dimension like he saved her, because it would change the past and prevent him from saving lives. Just because the original trilogy doesn't mention her doesn't mean she doesn't exist during that time. There was just no need to reference her.